# Change AssemblyCompany Attribute in UWP Projetct - AssemblyInfo.Versioning.AutoGenerated.cs Files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10, auto-generate, assembly-name

Always I rebuil my project, the files with name "AssemblyInfo.Versioning.AutoGenerated.cs" are generated. This files have some information like:

```
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company Name XPTO")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Project Name XYW")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright - Company Name XPTO")]
```

This files are generated for all project I have in my solution.
I need to change this values, but when I change, run the project, and values are restored.

Whats the problem?
How to change this permanently?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed any version control tool or somewhere in your code? By default this file's name should be "AssembyInfo.cs", and these assemblies can be modified in the file and won't be restored.

Comment: @Grace Feng - MSFT, I use only Visual Studio Online to version control. I try find the file "AssemblyInfo.cs" and I change this values. Thanks

Comment: So have you solve your problem? If not, you must make sure this "AssemblyInfo.cs" be checked out locally and have the edit permission.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, No solve my problem. In my AssemblyInfo.cs not have any referenct for "Project Name XYW" or "Company Name XPTO" :(

Comment: So, I think the AssemblyInfo.cs files of all your projects are fine, but there is a another file named "AssemblyInfo.Versioning.AutoGenerated.cs", this file is generated by VSO, and you can't modify it?

Comment: Did you use [Use a PowerShell script to customize your build process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/index) to build your project?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, yes, I have the file "AssemblyInfo.Versioning.AutoGenerated.cs" and I modify if necessary but when I run my project from studio, the values changed in "AssemblyInfo.Versioning.AutoGenerated.cs" are restored to previous data.

In this moment only use Studio to run project. I use PowerShell only when create package and install in another devite to test my app.
Thanks

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, Detail: I have some settings for the project start-up ("Debug", "Release", "XPTO", "TEST")

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT, If I add company name in Project>Properties>Assembly Information> Company name, Visual studio creates [assembly: AssemblyCompany(""Company Name"")] but give me an error: "Duplicate'AssemblyCompany' attribute